# Pandas read_csv() выдает ошибку ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, eof

В обработке файлов получаю их из разных источников и разных кодировок. Поэтому в цикле перебираю возможные кодировки из списка `en_codings = ['utf-8', "cp1250", "cp1251", "cp1252", "latin1", "utf-8-sig"]`  и работаю с той, при которой чтение произошло.

Параметры задачи позволяют пропускать "сбойные строки", поэтому использую параметр `on_bad_lines="skip"` в моем `pandas` версии 1.4.2.  И большинство файлов обрабатываются хоть как то.  Иногда встречаются "оборванный" файл, где в последней строке не все элементы.  Тогда, несмотря на `on_bad_lines="skip"` выдается ошибка `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 4390`,  хотя по моему разумению ее просто нужно было пропустить...

Файл прилагается: [csv файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1clfCcY49XI0CEEkI2RuTDV3_a-NZ_Hsp/view?usp=sharing).  Но вот так выглядит последние строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, последняя строчка оборвана.

Хотелось бы найти комбинацию параметров `pandas.read_csv()`, которая пропускала бы такой вариант плохой строчки.  Повторюсь  -  проблема в том, что она последняя.... такие же строчки в середине файла нормально пропускаются.
Ах да  -  Windows10.

**Добавлено.**  Проблема локализуется тем, что символ конца файла попался после открытой кавычки, которая инициировала новое поле.  Если кавычку ручками поставить  --  то файл считывается.

Comment: Вы на скриншоте показываете csv файл, а в ссылке - xlsx. файл по ссылке, сконвертированный из excel в csv у меня великолепно открывается. вероятно у вас что-то с переводом строки в последней строчки файла. либо выложите csv, либо посмотрите сами, что там с переводом строки.

Comment: Варианты из моего ответа пробовали, не работают?

Comment: По поводу перебора кодировок через цикл... https://pypi.org/project/chardet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd


with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    df = pd.DataFrame(reader)
```

Comment: Спасибо.  Попробую.
А в чем "прикол"?    `DictReader()`  умеет обрабатывать оборванные строчки лучше?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, Фиг знает. Просто возможно модуль корректней ошибки обрабатывает, а может наоборот менее требователен к формату. Главное, что работает )))

Comment: попробую. это интересно. Спасибо

Comment: Да, работает. Есть еще трюк. `read_csv `  -  имеет параметр `engine` По умолчанию он принят как С. Если установить на  `python`  падает в разы реже.  Во всяком случае - данный файл проходит )

Comment: Снова перекинул галочку ответа на твой вариант.  Ну и дело не в 10 баллах кармы )))   
Твой ответ - реально - жемчужина. Благодарю за помощь!!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, в 15-ти ))). На самом деле спасибо за фидбэк. Решение чисто интуитивное, самому практический результат был интересен. (всмысле не на одной табличке)

Comment: Но есть минусы.  Битые строки он не пропускает, а лепит из двух в одну как попало.....
Так что подумываю вернуться к идее  в случае необходимости лепить в конец файла кавычки и перечитывать через `read_csv` ))))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, ничто не идеально ))) Всегда чем-то приходится жертвовать

Answer (score 2):

Нашел такое решение после наводящего ответа @Namerek.

`pandas.read_csv`  - имеет параметр `engine` По умолчанию он принят как `С`. Если установить  `python` мой файл файл проходит.

Итак, решение выглядит так:

```
                readed_into_df = pd.read_csv(
                    str(file_name),
                    sep=separator,
                    encoding=en_coding,
                    on_bad_lines="skip",
                    engine='python',
                )
```

Главным в этом решении было добавление нового прараметра `engine='python'` .

**Обновление.**  Признаю решение за вариантом @Namerek. На мелких файлах мой вариант неплох. Но на 1.5Гб чтение затянулось на 40+ минут.  Все из за того, что парсится то Python кодом эти 5млн строк...
А вот трюк со чтением в словарь модулем `csv` справляется за минуту.
Так что - благодарю!!

Answer (score 0):

На [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016037/pandas-parsererror-eof-character-when-reading-multiple-csv-files-to-hdf5) предлагают добавить такие опции (попробуйте и по отдельности и вместе):

```
quoting=3, error_bad_lines=False
```

Фактически `3` - это `csv.QUOTE_NONE`, но чтобы писать в таком виде нужно подключать дополнительный модуль `import csv`, после этого можно писать в более понятном виде `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

Comment: еще хуже.  я нущупал один вариант. есть параметр engine/ По  умолчанию он равен C.  Когда меняю на python   -   работает.  А вообще придется самому парсить последнюю строку и перезаписывать файл перед импортом.   Я так думаю